# CSS Properties rules are not working in HTML file

Tags: html, css, notepad++

Please don't be too mean i am just trying to understand. Okay, so I am proficient in C++, Java, and C# for applications. I have recently been trying to understand web development. Right now i am going over basic HTML coding. Looking at http://www.westciv.com/style_master/academy/css_tutorial/introduction/how_they_work.html and and trying to recreate https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/How_CSS_works. But it is not working as intended.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <style type ="text/css"> <!-- You need this in order to have CSS, it has --> 
  p {color: blue; font-family:arial;}
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>This is my first CSS example</p>

    <ul>
      <li>This is</li>
      <li>a list</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

So when i type this code into Codepen it works as intended, With every paragraph displaying blue text. However, when i code it in notepad ++ as a HTML file it does not add the CSS style, format, background color, etc. Upon looking into it i found out if i add the style directly in the paragraph bracket it works (as shown below)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
     <style type ="text/css"> 
      p {color: blue;}
     </style>
      </head>
      <body>
     <p style="text-decoration: underline;">This is my body green</p>
     <p style = "color: blue;">this text should be blue!</p>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p>This is my first CSS example</p>

        <ul>
          <li>This is</li>
           <li>a list</li>
        </ul>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Adding declamation blocks like `<meta charset="utf-8>`and  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` has not helped either.

My question is why does this code work some places and not others? Is there a web browser setting that could be interfering? I have tried IE, FF, and Chrome but not of them will display the CSS style unless i specifically declare it with in the brackets not in the header. If it is a logical error please post/comment article to read.

Comment: @Kunok YUP that Worked!! How/Why does comment effect the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example the comment `<!-- You need this in order to have CSS, it has -->` is misplaced into a CSS declaration, so don't put HTML comments in a CSS declaration .

Declaring `p {color: blue; font-family:arial;}` only affects to `<P></P>` tags.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <style type ="text/css"> 
  p {color: blue; font-family:arial;}
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>This is my first CSS example</p>

    <ul>
      <li>This is</li>
      <li>a list</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you need to add specific formatting to specific tags you can use the `class` attribute (`class="blue"`), and declare a class in CSS appending a point at the beginning of the class name (`.blue`).

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
     <style type ="text/css"> 
            p {color: blue;}
            .underlined { text-decoration: underline }
            .blue {  color: blue }
     </style>
      </head>
      <body>
     <p class="underlined">This is my body green</p>
     <p class="blue" >this text should be blue!</p>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p>This is my first CSS example</p>

        <ul>
          <li>This is</li>
           <li>a list</li>
        </ul>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to declare a style type, as the only type is for CSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <style>
  p {color: blue; font-family:arial;}
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>This is my first CSS example</p>

    <ul>
      <li>This is</li>
      <li>a list</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why downvote? I removed the comment so it would work, and also defining the style type is not required.

Comment: At a guess, perhaps because your answer doesn't really add anything on top of the other answers?  Or maybe it was just a tactical downvote?

Comment: My comment was the first one, so it was the others were adding onto mine.